# determine number of bins for histogram

Tags: matlab, histogram

according to this link

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freedman%E2%80%93Diaconis_rule

and this link

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/798/calculating-optimal-number-of-bins-in-a-histogram-for-n-where-n-ranges-from-30

```
function m=histogram_bins(y);
m=floor(2*iqr(y))/(length(y)^(1/3));
end
```

but  for this  data

```
histogram_bins(Z)

ans =

    1.5791
```

i have tried histogram bins  as 2 and get following picture

[image]

but it is not correct  separation,so how can i fix it?

let us consider following example for another data to see what means good seperation

```
histogram_bins(B)

ans =

   17.4452

 histogram(B,100,18) % dont pay attention to 100
```

[image]

Comment: come one man,who downvoting?stop such  nonsense actions

Comment: please add to the question another histogram of your data with at least 50 bins - just for visualization.

Comment: i have  updated with another visualization

Comment: I know the question is about bin size, but what about using CDF rather than histogram? This would solve your issue as there is no bin anymore.

Comment: how can i use CDF there?let us suppose that we are talking about stochastic process ?we may use this http://www.ysumathstat.org/faculty/chang/class/s3717/06_1_Intro_Ch1_2_22_SturgeRule.pdf

Comment: any ideas?does there exist good method to determine number of bins?

Comment: A bunch of options from Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram#Number_of_bins_and_width. I think the big question is how many elements are in the vector that you are trying to find the histogram for? If you have too few, then no amount of bins will give you a nice looking histogram. Maybe that  empirical CDF idea is a better way to go.

Comment: for one case i have 294,but  it should be 2 times  more or 3 times more

Comment: You are reading the stats link wrong - that's an equation for bin **width**, not number of bins.

Comment: so that means that there is not best bins number?it should be decided by researcher?

Comment: @datodatuashvili Correct, there is no *best* number. But that wiki article provides you with a lot of formulae that provide good general options.

Comment: yes yes i see,of course  i can create a scripts for each to use in future

Comment: @datodatuashvili You can use CDF in any case. It is simply put just the integral of a PDF. You need to sort all of your (random) variables. If you get a new variable, it means you need to sort again the whole set.